# What is the generating function for this random walk?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, stochastic-processes, binomial-coefficients, random-walk

For a binomial random walk, each step $S_i$, can move up or down with equal step size with probability $1/2$, then we know that the generating function for the distribution of the summation:
$$S_1 + S_2 + ... + S_n$$

is:
$$\frac{1}{2^n}(1 + x)^n$$

Question 1: What is the generating function for the distribution of the this binomial random walk:

$$(S_1 + S_2 + ... + S_n)^2$$

Q2: As we know the distribution for the summation of regular binomial random walk will approach normal distribution in the continuous limit. What will be distribution of the above random walk in the continuous limit ?

Comment: $2^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} x^{k^2}$. There's no closed form for this.

Comment: @zhoraster, as we know the distribution for regular binomial random walk will approach normal distribution in the continuous limit. What will be distribution of the squared random walk in the continuous limit ?

Comment: One might think the limit is square Gaussian but in fact it is Gaussian too, I can elaborate if you wish (but then please add this to your question).

Comment: @zhoraster, Can you elaborate it ? I had edited my original question. (I thought the limit distribution of squared binominal random walk will be the squared root of Gaussian, something like exponential distribution. It seems that I was wrong.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for Q1 is $2^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} x^{k^2}$. There is no closed form for this sum.

Concerning Q2, denote $X_n = S_1 + \dots + S_n$ and write
$$
\frac{X_n^2 - n^2/4}{n\sqrt{n/4}} = \frac{X_n - n/2}{\sqrt{n/4}}\cdot \left(\frac{X_n}n + \frac12\right).
$$
The first term converges to the standard normal distribution thanks to CLT, the second one converges to 1 almost surely thanks to SLLN. So by Slutsky's theorem, the whole expression converges to the standard normal distribution. Put differently, $X_n^2\approx N(n^2/4, n^3/4$).

Comment: Thank you.  Intuitively, if $S_1 + S_2 + ... + S_n$ approaches to $e^{-x^2}$  in the limit (with some scaling factor,  then $(S_1 + S_2 + ... + S_n)^2$ should approach to $e^{-x}$  in the limit (with some scaling factor), what is wrong with intuition ?

Comment: @david It's just wrong. Your understanding of convergence in distribution and even of probability distribution seems to be very amiss.

Comment: Thank you. In your answer, should we denote $X_n = (S_1 + ... + S_n)^2$ , instead of $X_n = (S_1 + ... + S_n)$ ? Will this make a difference in your argument ?

Comment: Because the question is about the distribution of the $(S_1 + ... + S_n)^2$ not $(S_1 + ... + S_n)$ ?

Comment: @david if you watch closely, I look at $X_n^2$

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean, for any random variable $Y_n$, if $Y_n$ approach to a normal distribution in the limit, then $Y^2_n$ also approach to a normal distribution in the limit ? is this a general theorem ?

Comment: @david, yes! Keyword: delta-method.

Comment: @zhorster: thank you, let me take a look of delta-method.

Comment: @zhorster: Do you mean that,  for a sequence of random variable Yn, if Yn approach to a normal distribution in the limit, then $Y^2_n$ also approach to a normal distribution in the limit. This can not be true. Because we can choose all $Y_n$ to be same, and are  zero mean, normally distributed, then $Y^2_n$ can NOT be normally distributed.

Comment: @david, I didn't mean that. What I was speaking about is the case when $Y_n$ concentrate around their mean (e.g. have vanishing variance). The delta-method applies in this case.

Comment: Do you mean that the $X_n$ in the original question has vanishing variance ? I thought that variance for binomial random walk actually grows when $n->\infty $

Comment: @david, no, I'm talking about $X_n/n$.

Comment: thank you for answering my questions again.

Comment: @david, if all your questions are answered, you might wish to accept the answer.